# Which way to rotate a coin?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

The picture shows rotation of a coin in two ways along a axis passing through the centre of gravity.Which method is easier to rotate the coin?

Comment: Why do you think one rotation would be easier than the other? What makes rotation easy or hard?

Comment: You might want to start by reading a bit on moments of inertia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia

Answer (score 1):

The perpendicular axis theorem states that, (after defining an x, y, and z axis) the sum of rotational inertias around any two axes chosen is equal to the axis not chosen. In formula:
I<sub>x</sub> = I<sub>y</sub> + I<sub>z</sub>. Define the y-axis to be **axis 2** in your diagram. Then define the z-axis to **along the diameter of your circle but perpendicular to axis 2**. Continuing upon these defintions, **axis 1** must be the x-axis. Since rotations along the y-axis and z-axis are identical, the rotational inertias along these axes are the same: I<sub>y</sub> = I<sub>z</sub>. Therefore I<sub>x</sub> = 2I<sub>y</sub>, and the rotational inertia along the x-axis (or **axis 1**) is 2x greater than the rotation inertia along the y-axis (**axis 2**) and it is more difficult to rotate along axis 1.

Important Note: The perpendicular axis theorem assumes a planar object is being observed. In addition, when using  the formula: I<sub>x</sub> = I<sub>y</sub> + I<sub>z</sub>, the perpendicular axis theorem assumes that the y-axis and z-axis lie within the planar object being observed, and the x-axis is perpendicular to the plane that holds the planar object.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. If it was a sphere instead of a coin, all of your arguments would still hold and you would have to say that rotation about one axis was twice as hard as rotation about another, which is clearly absurd since a sphere is symmetrical about all three.

Comment: The perpendicular axis theorem only applies to objects that can fit within a plane. Good point though.